# Can I get/set data into WCF Service by Host?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF Service hosted on WindowsServiceHost (to communicate WindowsFormsApp <> WindowsServiceHost)

Is there any way get data from  WCFService to WindowsServiceHost?
And in other way (set data from WindowsServiceHost to WCFService)

That is what have i done:

1. I've made a project of WCF Service Library, implemented interface, contracts etc.
2. I created new project - Windows service and added reference to project from #1 and to System.ServiceModel
3. Configured app.conf:

   ```
   <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
     <netTcpBinding>
       <binding name="netTcp">
         <security mode="Message">
         </security>
       </binding>
     </netTcpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="mexBehavior">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
       </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="KSPDJOBWinWCFService.KSPDJOBWinWCFService" >
       <endpoint address="KSPDJOBWinWCFService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="KSPDJOBWinWCFService.IKSPDJOBWinWCFService" bindingConfiguration="netTcp" />
       <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8079"/>
           <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090"/>
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>
     </service>
   </services>
   ```
4. I've hosted the WCF in OnStart method of Windows Service

   ```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
       host = new ServiceHost(typeof(KSPDJOBWinWCFService.KSPDJOBWinWCFService));
       host.Open();
   }
   ```
5. Added new solution with WinformsClient app (as WCF Client) and tested communication - all working fine.
6. The problem is when i send a value from WinFormsClient to WCF Service, and want to read it from Windows Service aplication

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: Are you hosting your WCF Service inside a Windows Service (another service derived by `ServiceBase`), that you have implemented? And between those services you want to exchange data, is that correct? If so, could you paste the code how your WCF Service is hosted?

Comment: Hi Mark i Answered You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hold the WCF service instance in a global variable and work with events. In this sample the WCF Service `KSPDJOBWinWCFService` exposes an event `EventA` and the Service Host will handle it. This is the place where you can process the values sent by your WCF Client.

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    private ServiceHost _host;
    private KSPDJOBWinWCFService _instance;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            _instance = new KSPDJOBWinWCFService();
            _instance.EventA += HandleEventA;
            _host = new ServiceHost(_instance);
            _host.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Logging
        }
    }

    public void HandleEventA(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        // do whatever you want here
        var localVar = e.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_instance != null)
            {
                _instance.Dispose();
            }
            _host.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Logging
        }
    }
}
```

The WCF Service then fires this event together with the values sent from the WCF client:

```
public class KSPDJOBWinWCFService : IKSPDJOBWinWCFService
{
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> EventA;

    public bool SomeWcfOperation(int value)
    {
        EventA?.Invoke(this, new CustomEventArgs(value));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Create event args that fulfill your needs:

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public CustomEventArgs(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

You can also expose values with public properties in your WCF Service. But events are also necessary.

Comment: Working like a Harm :)) Thank You Marc for nice tutorial. I had to add `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]` below my WCFService class: `public class KSPDJOBWinWCFService : IKSPDJOBWinWCFService`